# How to make a map of range to a single value?

Tags: node.js, language-agnostic

What's the data structure of choice to map a range to a single value? E.g. `a` has values 1-1000, `b` has values 1001-20000, what would be an efficient way to answer the question "what is the key of 11234?" (answer: `b`). The most straighforward way would be too look through all the keys and check if range contains the searched value, but it seems that its performance would get worse with every new key.

In my particular case I'd prefer a node.js solution, but I suppose it should not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use any balanced tree. sort ranges by lower bound but in a node keep also info about the higher bound and of course your mapped value.

```
   1001 (20000, a)
  /
1 (1000, b)
```

then when you look for a key `x`, always return the max key not grater than `x`. it's a standard binary tree lookup O(log n). in the node you have information about the range so you can check if `x` is within range.

when you look for 11234 you will get the node `1001 (20000 b)`. 11234 is inside 1001-20000 so your value is `b`. if you look for 0 you will get null/none so your key is not mapped. if you look for 1000,5 you will get `1 (1000 a)`. 1000,5 is out of that range so your key is not mapped.

of course your ranges can't overlap

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly, but would not it take the same number of steps to get the answer, and sorting ranges by min value, then looping until max is greater then searched value?

Comment: building a balanced tree is O(n log n). later every query is O(log n)